# probability for dummies: how to calculate the probability of an event?

Tags: probability

Here's what I am starting with: The probability of an event in a random experiment is basically the value of its relative frequency if we repeat the experiment infinitely (I completely ignore the Bayesian view a this point).

So if I have an exercise like this:

- There are 6 red and 4 blue plastic chips in a cup. What is the
  probability of retrieving a red one?

The answer would be 6/10 because that is the relative frequency we expect?

And when we have an exercise like this:

- Calculate in a Bernoulli experiment the probability of having one
  broken lamp after testing 10 lamps

and the probability of getting a broken lamp is given as 1/3, then this probability is the value the relative frequency of this event would assume after an infinite amount of tries?

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  For the second question, are you familiar with the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

The formula of probability you are talking about is the following
$$P(E)={\lim_{n\to {\infty}}}{r\over n}$$ Where event E occurs $r$ times in $n$ trials. This formula is used for random experiments.

This is not required in your question as the probability has already been calculated and given to you. So the answer will be-
$$P=\text {ways to choose 1 lamp out of 10}\times P(\text { 1 lamp breaks})\times P(\text { 9 lamps don't break})$$
$$P={10\choose 1}\times{1\over 3}\times \biggl(1-{1\over 3}\biggl)^9$$
$$P=10\times {1\over 3}\times\biggl({2\over 3}\biggl)^9$$
$$P={10\cdot2^9\over 3^{10}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the first exercise I would rather say that our mathematical model of the situation will - if it is a *reasonable* model - be constructed in such a way that the probability of retrieving a red one equals $\frac6{10}$.

But answering such a question given as exercise is not exactly the same thing as constructing a model for the situation. For answering you must formally look at the model (provided that it is there already) and your answer must be based on that model.

If nothing is said about the model (and this happens frequently) then you are allowed to assume that the model is *reasonable*. Actually in that situation you are free to construct such a model yourself.